# Proving continuity of the solution to a simple integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I'm trying to show the continuity of the solution to this simple integral
equation (or the corresponding ODE):
$$
x(t)=x(0)+at-b\int_0^t x(s)\wedge u(s) \, ds,\quad t\in[0,T]
$$
where $x(s)\wedge u(s)=\min(x(s),u(s))$ and $u$ is a piecewise constant (right-continious)
function, i.e., 
$$
u(s)=u_k,\quad t_{k}\leq s<t_{k+1},
$$
$t_0=0$ and $t_{k+1}-t_k=c<T$ is a constant.

I haven't been able to find any general results. I'd be grateful if
you could point me to such results or give me a hint in proving the
statement. Perhaps bounding $\left|x(t)-x(t_1)\right|$ and taking
$t\rightarrow t_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is continuous on $t$ and so **any** solution (say measurable) of the integral equation will be continuous (the right-hand side is continuous and so the left-hand side is continuous).

Comment: Thanks. Is it trivial that the integral is continuous? Or needs some argument like "because it's derivative exists almost everywhere"?

Comment: We know that $\int_s^t \text{integrable function}\to0$ when $t\to s$, so if we take say bounded measurable functions, one could say that it is "trivial" without any damage.